# Disbable rest of the page when progress loading is running....!

Tags: javascript, jsp, spinner

I am new to Javascript

I have written simple javascript to show progress using animated gif.

Problem is though it is working fine , I can able to click on the form below that gif image.

Can anyone guide me..??

my js function is

```
function search()
{
    /* doOverlayOpen('dvLoading', 470); */
    var opts = {
          lines: 17, // The number of lines to draw
          length: 10, // The length of each line
          width: 4, // The line thickness
          radius: 21, // The radius of the inner circle
          corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
          rotate: 13, // The rotation offset
          color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb
          speed: 1, // Rounds per second
          trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
          shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
          hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
          className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
          zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
          top: 'auto', // Top position relative to parent in px
          left: 'auto' // Left position relative to parent in px
        };
    var target = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
    ...Some code.....!!!!!
}
```

Comment: before showing that image you have to provide masking to the page .

Comment: how to achieve masking ... can you please give me an idea or link... i dont have much knowledge about js

Comment: you can find a  nice and sinple tutorial here ..
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-loadmask/

Comment: getting mask with javascript somewhat tricky  so please include jquery library ..so you can proceed with your stuff ...